# Out Of Memory Exception - Loading Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, out-of-memory, .net-6.0, datarow

I am trying to create a datatable and load a single row in to the datatable. I am using this datatable as table type parameter. But this method is enclosed in a ParallelProcessor. Some records are being updated but for some I get the below Out of memory exception.

```
ParallelProcessor.EnqueueAsync(() =>
{
public DataTable Getrecords(List<testData> testData)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            var data = testData.Select(x => x.ID);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                dr["ID"] = item;
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return table;
        }
});
ParallelProcessor.WaitForQueueCompletion();
```

Below is the error which I get for some records

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> at System.Data.RBTree`1.TreePage..ctor(Int32 size) at System.Data.RBTree`1.AllocPage(Int32 size)
> at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNewNode(K key)
> at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
> at System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)

It is perfectly working on some environments.

Comment: What means "it is enclosed in ParallelProcessor"? Show that code please. Loading a `DataTable` with a single row is certainly not the problem, but the way you use it.

Comment: "Parallel" and "DataTable" in combination sounds suspicious. If there is any concurrency going on, are you *sure* it is thread safe?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have update the code with ParallelProcessor. Kindly help

Comment: @JonasH I have updated the code with ParallelProcessor. Kindly help